# Career page on corporate site or dedicated platform?

Tags: customer-experience, customer

I'm looking for studies, data or opinions from experts who have already encountered this problem.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of having a candidate path to apply on a single website?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of having a candidate path to apply on a dedicated platform?
Is one or the other solution better? Are there any technical constraints to take into account?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are we assuming that the dedicated platform could be accessible through web, or not? If not, what would be the platform hosting options?

Comment: Please be more specific. What are the considerations and what do you want to find out about them exactly?

Comment: Yes, the platform would be accessible through web. For example, as the experience on this website : https://www.axa.com/ when you click on Careers > Apply, you are redirected to the careers platform. But is it a good practice or is it better to have all the experience on one platform? (all the experience on the corporate website I mean).